# adding a dataframe to another dataframe under a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and I'm stuck with this task of adding the contents of a dataframe to another dataframe. I'm getting historical data for tickers using the yfinance library which returns a dataframe

```
def get_fin_data(ticker):
  temp = mean_df[ticker].dropna()
  dates = [date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for date in temp.index.tolist()]
  start_end_dates = update_start_end_dates([dates[0], dates[-1]])
  data = yf.download(ticker, start=start_end_dates[0], end=start_end_dates[1])
  return data

for ticker in tickers:
  df_eod_price = get_fin_data(ticker)
  df_eod_price2 = df_eod_price.drop(['Open', 'High','Low','Close','Volume'], axis=1) # drop unwanted rows
  df_eod_price2['Returns'] = df_eod_price2['Adj Close']/df_eod_price2['Adj Close'].shift(1) - 1 # calculate daily returns  
  print(df_eod_price2.head())
```

[image: get_fin_data() return]

I want to add these price datas to the relevant ticker which I have in the following dataframe.

```
mean_df = df.groupby(['ticker', 'date']).mean()
print(mean_df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're still looking for a solution:

I assume that your base dataframe `df_mean` looks somethinig like:

```
                   compound
ticker date                
AMZN   2021-11-17         1
       2021-11-18         2
       2021-11-19         3
       2021-11-22         4
       2021-11-23         5
FB     2021-11-22         1
       2021-11-23         2
```

I also assume that `ticker` is something like a list that contains ticker strings:

```
ticker = ["AMZN", "FB"]
```

Then you could do something like:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df_mean.index.get_level_values("date"))
start, end = dates.min().date(), (dates.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).date()
df = (
    yf.download(ticker, start=start, end=end)
      .stack(level=1)
      .drop(columns=["Close", "High", "Low", "Open", "Volume"])
      .rename(columns={"Adj Close": "returns"})
      .reorder_levels([1, 0])
      .sort_index(level=0)
)
df.index = df.index.rename(["ticker", "date"])
```

This is doing one download instead of one per ticker. Therefore the `start`/`end` values are based on the `min`/`max` of the `date` column. (This might download a bit more data than needed.)

Result looks like:

```
                       returns
ticker date                   
AMZN   2021-11-17  3549.000000
       2021-11-18  3696.060059
       2021-11-19  3676.570068
       2021-11-22  3572.570068
       2021-11-23  3580.040039
FB     2021-11-17   340.769989
       2021-11-18   338.690002
       2021-11-19   345.299988
       2021-11-22   341.010010
       2021-11-23   337.250000
```

Now [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the results with `df_mean`

```
df_mean = df_mean.merge(df, on=["ticker", "date"], how="left")
```

or set

```
df_mean["returns"] = df.returns
```

and then calculate the returns

```
df_mean.returns = df_mean.groupby("ticker").returns.pct_change()
```

Resulting `df_mean`:

```
                   compound   returns
ticker date                          
AMZN   2021-11-17         1       NaN
       2021-11-18         2  0.041437
       2021-11-19         3 -0.005273
       2021-11-22         4 -0.028287
       2021-11-23         5  0.002091
FB     2021-11-22         1       NaN
       2021-11-23         2 -0.011026
```

Comment: you’re a legend ! Thankss